# .NET Array of references

Tags: c#, reference

In .NET we are given `System.Span<T>` which allows direct referencing to continuous memory. It is generally constructed by giving it an existing array. However, what if I want to be able to create an array of references to discontinuous elements in an array?

For instance, given:

```
var array = new double[ 5 ] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var span = new Span( array ); // Continuous references, [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

What if I wanted to take `array` and create a "span" that can have a different arrangement of values while still referencing the value stored in the array? Such as:

```
var discontinuous = new DiscontinuousSpan[3] { 
  (reference of array[1]), 
  (reference of array[0]), 
  (reference of array[4]) };

discontinuous[ 0 ]; // 2 (reference of array[1])
discontinuous[ 1 ]; // 1 (reference of array[0])
discontinuous[ 2 ]; // 5 (reference of array[4])
```

I've looked at the documentation of `Span<T>` and understand that it's just a pointer to memory with a fixed length. However, **with the C# 7.2 addition of references to value types, shouldn't discontinuous referencing of array elements work?** I don't see any .NET types that do so, so I assume that I would have to implement something like this myself with a custom value type.

**Clarification**: The main goal is to have this support `System.Numerics.Vector<T>` so that I can perform SIMD on discontinuous references.

Comment: I am a little unclear on your terminology here and how it relates, What do you mean by *"discontinuous*" do you mean just a `Span` of references/pointers?

Comment: Pretty much. I'd just like to create a `Span` (or something similar) with select elements from the array, so when I read to or write from the values in the span they reflect the changes in the array. E.g. `discontinuous[0]` is a reference of `array[1]`, `discontinuous[2]` is a reference of `array[4]`

Comment: It would be straightforward to write a `PermutedArrayAccessor` class with overloaded `this[int index]` that does what you asked, however it would not have any relationship with `Span` and would not be compatible with library functions that accept `Span` objects.

Comment: @BenVoigt A solid idea that would get the job done. I am hoping to accomplish two things with this: performance and `System.Numerics.Vector<T>` support. What you suggest would be even more efficient if it handled pointer arithmetic via unsafe code to skip the CLR's bounds checking, so altogether that would properly handle the desired abstraction. The Numerics support, however, is a different story...

Comment: You can try constructing your own ref struct from multiple spans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you have an array with numbers and want to have separate references to segment of that array. But Span is a special kind of value type, which cannot be passed around.
So, you must store the info to generate those separate spans only when needed...

```
// Here we store index and length for each desired segment
var mySegments = new (int position, int length)[] { (17, 5), (48, 19), (79, 16) };
```

Then, when neede to be accessed...

```
double [100] Numbers = GetNumbersFromSomwhere();

public double[] GetSegment(int segmentIndex)
{
   var segment = mySegments[segmentIndex];
   var reference = new Span<double>(Numbers, segment.position, segment.length);
   return reference.ToArray();
}
```

However, that final ToArray() will instantiate a new object array (which generates GC pressure). Therefore, maybe you could store and access your data as byte-array (obviously  considering the 8 bytes of length of each double), to generate separate spans of double. And later finally get your values with a func like this for reading a specific double:

```
    // Converts a Span into a double
    // Requires using System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe
    public static double ToDouble(ReadOnlySpan<byte> value)
    {
        if (value.Length < sizeof(double))
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value));
        return Unsafe.ReadUnaligned<double>(ref MemoryMarshal.GetReference(value));
    }
```

Hope it helps for your Vector (fixed type, I pressume) case.